# Red/Black deployment strategy terminates older server group even if the new server group fails to become healthy

Tags: amazon-web-services, spinnaker, blue-green-deployment

Red/Black deployment strategy terminates older server group even if the new server group fails to become healthy.

- Cloud Provider: AWS
- Environment: Local Ubuntu
- Feature Area: Pipelines

During a deploy stage in pipeline execution, the older server group gets disabled despite the newer server group unable to become healthy. This should not happen according to the documentation. Instead of the older server group being disabled, the new server group should be disabled if health checks could not be passed.

screenshot of deployment config.

[image: pipeline deployment config]

I have also configured the server group to use health status from the load balancer.

[image: server group health check status]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling *Consider only cloud provider health when executing tasks* in Application attributes enables the pipeline to wait for new server group to become healthy before removing older server group from the target group.